# Propotional growth in difference equations

Tags: difference-equations

Xn denoting the number of affected children after n weeks. Initially, 2 children were affected and 3 more reported affected in the first week of the outbreak.

I know X0 = 2 but I am confused with X1=?

X1 = 5 or X1 = 3 ??

Comment: Whole Question - In a school, 500 children are not vaccinated against smallpox. Trend analysis of an outbreak of smallpox has shown that the number of new cases of smallpox reported in the school per week was proportional to (i) the number of children already affected and (ii) the number of unaffected children amongst the non-vaccinated children. Express this is a difference equation of sequence {Xn}, Xn denoting the number of affected children after n weeks.

Comment: I've gone and submitted an edit to move the question into your post. In the future please edit your post to include relevant information instead of putting it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If the original 2 are still affected, then X1=5; if not, X1=3.

Comment: I just added a comment you can check for the clarity of the question.